# How to hide key field in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

[image: Tableau example]I'm using 2 data sources connected by 'product' field: one source contains category information, other - net sales data. Result is shown attached:

[image: example]

Example is shown in Excel but it's the same in Tableau. 
The problem is that I don't need Product column and I just want to see a pivot table like in attached picture.
Is it possible in Tableau?

Comment: When you say 2 data sources, do you mean you are using Tableau data blending? Do you see orange bars next to any fields? Or are you using joins? If using excel for instance, is your data in one file on separate tabs? Or in two separate files? It could be as simple as taking Product off the Rows shelf or slightly more complex depending on the answers to those questions

Answer (score 0):

Recreate the subcategory so you can join on that. On your data source that has both, place product on rows then place subcategory. Copy that crosstab to excel. Use this WHEN THEN Builder found here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60455118/WHEN%20THEN%20builder.xlsx to quickly make the components of a CASE statement formula. Then join the data sources on subcategory. .

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Bernando, but unfortunately that's not a solution: rows for each products are still present and I want to see only subcategories with totals (like in the second table in my example). It's not convenient to compare results per categories when I have more then 100 rows per products in each. I attached another picture 'Tableau example' where products are already hidden.

Comment: changed my answer.